# Problema al graficar con Highcharts y AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, highcharts

Estoy tratando de realizar un gráfico dinámico, que me pase los datos por AJAX, que al seleccionar un `MES`me grafique segun resultado, pasa que en la consola del navegador me muestra resultados segun la consulta pero no me gráfica, y si coloco resultados predeterminados los muestra, pero cuando cambio de mes se coloca en blanco el gráfico. ayuda por favor. adjunto todo el código.

**HTML**

```
<script src="../Highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../Highcharts/js/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="caja">
    <select name="ANO" id="ANO" autofocus="autofocus">
        <option>Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="caja">
    <select name="MES" id="MES">
        <option>Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="01">ENERO</option>
        <option value="02">FEBRERO</option>
        <option value="03">MARZO</option>
        <option value="04">ABRIL</option>
        <option value="05">MAYO</option>
        <option value="06">JUNIO</option>
        <option value="07">JULIO</option>
        <option value="08">AGOSTO</option>
        <option value="09">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="10">OCTUBRE</option>
        <option value="11">NOVIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="12">DICIEMBRE</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

jQuery(function ($) {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
      renderTo: 'container'
  },

  series: [{
    name : "Planillas recibidas por dia",
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


     }]
  });

  $( "#MES" ).change(function() {
  //validamos las fechass
  var ANO = $('#ANO').val();
  var MES = $('#MES').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "procesar_estadistica.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { ANO: ANO, MES: MES }
  })

  .done(function(data) {

  console.log(data);
  console.log(ANO);
  console.log(MES);

  chart.series[0].setData(data.resultado);

    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/conexion.php'); ?> 


<?php 

$MES = $_POST['MES']; 
$ANO = $_POST['ANO']; 
$resultado = [];


for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
$query= "SELECT SUM(PLANILLA) AS r FROM acta_entrega WHERE 
DAY(FECHA_E_FAC)='$i' AND MONTH(FECHA_E_FAC)='$MES' AND YEAR(FECHA_E_FAC) = 
'$ANO'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query, $conexion); 
$valor = mysql_result($result, 0); 
$resultado[] = round($valor, 1); 
} 

$data = array("resultado" => $resultado); 
echo json_encode($data); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de varios días, pero publico la solución por si a alguien le sirve:

Lo único que faltaba era declarar el tipo de datos por la cual se llaman los resultados:

```
$( "#MES" ).change(function() {

  var ANO = $('#ANO').val();
  var MES = $('#MES').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "procesar.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { ANO: ANO, MES: MES },
    dataType: "json"
 })

.done(function(data) {

  console.log(data);
  console.log(ANO);
  console.log(MES);

  chart.series[0].setData(data);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas retornando un array e array:

```
$data = array("resultado" => $resultado); 
echo json_encode($data);
```

Intenta enviando la variable `$resulado` en si:

```
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Entonces en tu javascript la forma de obtener la respuesta seria:

```
  //...
 .done(function(data) {
     chart.series[0].setData(data)
 });
```

Aqui un ejemplo de como seria:

```js
  $(function($) {
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
              renderTo: 'container'
          },

          series: [{
              name: "Planillas recibidas por dia",
              data:[1,2,3,4,2,1],
          }]
      });

      $("#MES").change(function() {
          
          var ANO = $('#ANO').val();
          var MES = $('#MES').val();
          console.log(MES);
          $.ajax({
                  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1261v5",
                  method: "get",
                  data: {
                      ANO: ANO,
                      MES: MES
                  }
              })
              .done(function(data) {
                  chart.series[0].setData(data);
              });
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div class="caja">
    <select name="ANO" id="ANO" autofocus="autofocus">
        <option>Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="caja">
    <select name="MES" id="MES">
        <option>Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="01">ENERO</option>
        <option value="02">FEBRERO</option>
        <option value="03">MARZO</option>
        <option value="04">ABRIL</option>
        <option value="05">MAYO</option>
        <option value="06">JUNIO</option>
        <option value="07">JULIO</option>
        <option value="08">AGOSTO</option>
        <option value="09">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="10">OCTUBRE</option>
        <option value="11">NOVIEMBRE</option>
        <option value="12">DICIEMBRE</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Einer hice lo que me dijiste pero sigue sin graficar, lo único diferente es que ahora me muestra un linea de parámetros en la parte de abajo, pero es como si no obtuviera datos

Answer (score 0):

hola amigo veo que tuviste el mismo problema me podrias ayudar, tampoco mi pinta la grafica, no se donde esta el detalle en php o javascript.
este es mi codigo donde hago la consulta_reporte

```
    <?php

    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = '5432';
    $database = 'pos';
    $user = 'postgres';
    $password = '';

    $cnx = pg_connect(
      'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database .
      ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password
  );

    $qr = "select * from vw_dhqc_report";

    $year = 'year';
    $id_control = 'id_control';
    $element = 'element';



    // header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
    $query4 = "SELECT
        DISTINCT year, id_control, element,
        returned_value, expected_value,
        sample_id, min_2std, plus_3std, plus_2std
      FROM vw_dhqc_report
      WHERE
      '$_POST[$year]' = year AND 
      '$_POST[$id_control]'= id_control AND
      '$_POST[$element]'= element
    ";
    $result4 = pg_query($query4);


    $resutado = array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result4)) {
      $resutado[] = $row;
    }
    http_response_code(200);
    header("Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8");
    // echo json_encode($resutado);
    pg_close($cnx);

    ?>
```

este es mi index.php donde lleno los combos

```
<form  id="formulario" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Seleccione una Opci&oacute;n<h3>
    <!-- <h3>year</h3> -->
    <select name="year" id="year_id">
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <?php
     $query = "select distinct $year from vw_dhqc_report order by year desc";
     $result = pg_query($query);

     while($fila=pg_fetch_array($result)){
     echo "<option value='".$fila['year']."'>".$fila['year']."</option>";
     }
    ?>
    </select>
    <!-- <h3>id_control</h3> -->
    <select name="id_control" id="control_id">
    <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
     </select>
     <!-- <h3>Element</h3> -->
     <select name="element" id="element_id">
    <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
     </select>
    <br><br>
      <?php

      ?>
    </form>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#year_id').on('change', function(){
            var year = $(this).val();
            if(year){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: 'control.php',
                    data:'year='+year,
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#control_id').html(data);   
                  }   

                }); 
            }else{
                $('#control_id').html('<option value="">Select year</option>');
            }
        });

    $('#control_id').on('change', function(){
            var id_control = $(this).val();
            var year =$('#year_id').val();

            // var  element = {'year':year,'id_control':id_control};
            if(id_control){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'element.php',
                     data: element = {'year':year,'id_control':id_control},

                    success:function(data){
                        $('#element_id').html(data);


                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#element_id').html('<div value="">Select id_control</div>');
            }
         });
      $('#element_id').on('change', function(){
            var id_element = $(this).val();
            var year =$('#year_id').val();
             var id_control =  $('#control_id').val();

            if(id_element){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'consulta_reporte.php',

                    data: element = {'element':id_element,'year':year,'id_control':id_control},

                    success:function(data){
                        $('#resultado').html(data);


                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#resultado').html('<div value="">Mostrar Tabla</div>');
            }
         });
        });
      </script>

<div id="resultado">

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

este es mi javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "consulta_reporte.php",

    success : function(data){
      alert(data);

      var sample_id = [];
      var expected_value_reporte = [];
      var min_2std_reporte = [];
      var plus_2std_reporte = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        sample_id.push(data[i].sample_id);
        expected_value_reporte.push(data[i].expected_value);
        min_2std_reporte.push(data[i].min_2std);
        plus_2std_reporte.push(data[i].plus_2std);
      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: sample_id,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "expected_value",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            data: expected_value_reporte
          },
          {
            label: "min_2std",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            data: min_2std_reporte
          },
          {
            label: "plus_2std",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            data: plus_2std_reporte
          } 
        ]
      };

      var ctx = $("#resultado");

      var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata
      });
    },
    error : function(data) {

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: La zona de respuestas no es espacio para exponer dudas o comentarios, por favor elimina esto, lee [ask] y abre una nueva pregunta

Comment: tengo el mismo problema amigo no me pinta las graficas

Comment: Si sin embargo sigue por favor las indicaciones ya dadas, pues este espacio es solo para exponer respuestas y no preguntas